# Using Regular Expressions in Xpath in R

Tags: regex, xml, r, xpath

I am trying to match a set of XML nodes using R. The nodes have the structure which is name#. I know this could easily be matched with a regular expression but I can't seem to get it to work in R. Here is an example.

Nodes I want to match:

```
<matrix4>...</matrix>
<matrix5>...</matrix>
<matrix2>...</matrix>
```

I am accessing the nodes using the XML package:

```
library("XML")
...
getNodeSet(head_node, ".//matrix2|.//matrix4|.//matrix5")
```

I have been trying to use the matches function but I can seem to get it to work. I am not sure R supports matches or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: XPath 1.0 does not support regular expressions and `XML`/`xml2` only support XPath 1.0

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, that is unfortunate. Is there any similar package I could use that does support regular expressions?

Comment: You can also use a vector of path strings like `getNodeSet(doc, paste0("//matrix", c(2,4,5)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple ways to do this without regular expressions:

```
# with XML ----------------------------------------------------------------

library(XML)

doc <- xmlParse("<set>
<matrix4>...</matrix4>
<matrix5>...</matrix5>
<matrix2>...</matrix2>
</set>")

# a bit generic (i.e. useless if you need to only choose certain "matrix" tags)
getNodeSet(doc, "//*[starts-with(name(), 'matrix')]")

## [[1]]
## <matrix4>...</matrix4> 
## 
## [[2]]
## <matrix5>...</matrix5> 
## 
## [[3]]
## <matrix2>...</matrix2> 
## 
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "XMLNodeSet"

# closer to what you need
getNodeSet(doc, "//*[name()='matrix4' or name()='matrix2']")
## [[1]]
## <matrix4>...</matrix4> 
## 
## [[2]]
## <matrix2>...</matrix2> 
## 
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "XMLNodeSet"

# with xml2 ---------------------------------------------------------------

library(xml2)

doc <- read_xml("<set>
<matrix4>...</matrix4>
<matrix5>...</matrix5>
<matrix2>...</matrix2>
</set>")

# a bit generic (i.e. useless if you need to only choose certain "matrix" tags)
xml_find_all(doc, "//*[starts-with(name(), 'matrix')]")
## {xml_nodeset (3)}
## [1] <matrix4>...</matrix4>
## [2] <matrix5>...</matrix5>
## [3] <matrix2>...</matrix2>

# closer to what you need    
xml_find_all(doc, "//*[name()='matrix4' or name()='matrix2']")
## {xml_nodeset (2)}
## [1] <matrix4>...</matrix4>
## [2] <matrix2>...</matrix2>
```

Comment: Isn't the second method essentially the same thing that I am already doing? The first method is closer to what I want but I would like to only match matrix followed by a number, sometimes the node starts with matrix and is followed by something else.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, you can't use regular expression, but you could generate different path strings.

```
doc <- xmlParse("<set>
  <matrixA>...</matrixA>
  <matrix2>...</matrix2>
  <matrixC>...</matrixC>
  <matrix421>...</matrix421>
  <matrix55>...</matrix55>
</set>")

#exact numbers matching matrix2, 4 or 5
getNodeSet(doc, paste0("//matrix", c(2,4,5)))
[[1]]
<matrix2>...</matrix2> 

#matching ANY Number
getNodeSet(doc, paste0("//*[starts-with(name(), 'matrix", 0:9, "')]"))
[[1]]
<matrix2>...</matrix2> 
[[2]]
<matrix421>...</matrix421> 
[[3]]
<matrix55>...</matrix55> 

# or maybe use a regular expression on the names and then index
n <-grep("matrix[0-9]", xpathSApply(doc, "//set/*", xmlName))
getNodeSet(doc, "//set/*")[n]
```